# What are the differences between "the pen as a sword" and "pen as sword"?

Tags: grammar

I've seen people omit the articles for whatever reason, so I was wondering why it was done, and if "the pen as a sword" is or can be equivalent to the phrase "pen as sword".

The issue is that "pen as sword" can mean a number of thing due to the lack of articles.

It can mean "a pen as a sword", "the pen as a sword", "a pen as the sword" and "the pen as the sword".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I look up "Pen as Sword" on Google, the only examples I find are in article titles.  In the title of a book, academic article, or newspaper article, definite and indefinite articles are often omitted for brevity.  In a sentence, you would have to use the the articles.

Take a look at the answers here:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38759/dropping-articles-in-the-title-of-an-article-or-a-section-or-in-the-caption-o